# how to make unique field in SELECT(get only first)

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I got a problem with SQL statment, I am trying to make START field unique. What I mean is to DELETE rest fields which has the same value in this field.

My SQL query:

```
SELECT s.date AS 
START , s.machine_id, s.stop_id, o.date AS 
STOP 
FROM stops s
LEFT JOIN performance_v2 o ON o.date > s.date
AND o.machine_id = s.machine_id
AND impuls_count > 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get you only the eraliest START in a single column. You can use it standalone or as a subquery.

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.date AS [START] AS 
STOP 
FROM stops s
LEFT JOIN performance_v2 o ON o.date > s.date
AND o.machine_id = s.machine_id
AND impuls_count > 0
ORDER BY s.date
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `SELECT DISTINCT s.date AS START, ...`

Also, maybe the `GROUP BY` clause is what you're looking for. You could try appending `GROUP BY s.date` to the end of your query.